# Macro representing a pin on a microchip

Tags: c, macros, atmega

I'm trying to write some code in C for an atmega microcontroller and I have a working macro `BIT_SET` for setting a single bit:

```
#define BIT_MASK(b)  (0x01 << (b))
#define BIT_ON(p,b)  ((p) |= BIT_MASK(b))
#define BIT_OFF(p,b) ((p) &= ~BIT_MASK(b))
#define BIT_SET(p,b,v) (v ? BIT_ON(p,b) : BIT_OFF(p,b))
```

Now I'd like to define one-line macros representing I/O pins. Something similar to this:

```
#define LED B,5    // an LED diode is connected to bit 5 of port B
#define BUTTON B,4 // a button is connected to bit 4 of port B
```

<sub>There will be more of these macros for different peripheries in a final code, this is only a simplified example.</sub>

**The problem is** that I don't know how to define macros `PORT` and `DDR`,
so that I could use the `LED` (or `BUTTON`) macro like this:

```
BIT_SET(DDR(LED), 1);  // which should expand to: BIT_SET(DDRB, 5, 1)
BIT_SET(PORT(LED), 0); // which should expand to: BIT_SET(PORTB, 5, 0)
```

This is my motivation:

The `DDRB` line controls a direction of the pin (whether the pin is an input or an output),
the `PORTB` line sets a logical value of the output pin.
Because both the lines affect the same pin, I'd like to select the pin in 1 place (`#define LED ...`)
and later in a code use only symbolic names (`LED`, `BUTTON`) for both operations (configuring direction and setting an output value).

Macros `DDRB` and `PORTB` must be able to expand further (and not only once), because they're defined in an external header (not under my control).
Also I was trapped by a fact that concatenation using `##` prevents further expansion of the macro.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use inline functions?

Comment: @WeatherVane You're probably right, it could be a better way. An enumeration for ports, maybe a struct for keeping port and pin together. And let a compiler to do the optimizations for me.

Comment: I suppose you try flipping things around, i.e. `#define LED(p) p(B, 5)`, `#define PORT(a,b) PORT##a`, `#define PIN(a,b) (b)`, `BIT_SET(LED(PORT), LED(PIN))`. Ugly as sin though.

Comment: I am against the use of macros, apart from simple parameter substitution, where the end result is to create a "new" language that those who follow you will have to learn or untangle. I would use them only when there is no language syntax available.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The nasty thing about accessing these type of registers is many MCU vendors have a penchant for making them fairly non-orthogonal, with slightly different layouts and feature sets across arrays of mostly-equivalents peripherals. Presumably this saves silicon space but it also serves to complicate writing generic code, and in attempting it I frequently either end up with macro hacks to bind things by name or with endless specializations. In this limited case the clean way is certainly workable but things get hairy when you need to specify the interrupt vector for port B, say.

Comment: @doynax if I would not even try to write generic code that works on every MCU. I would separate every MCU specific thing into its own file, and separate form from functionality. That way, I could write C code that would "run" on a PC, before the hardware was available. Motivated by the hardware not being available until 2 days before product release.

Comment: @WeatherVane: There certainly should be a hardware-abstraction layer at a higher level kept as separate as performance allows. I was referring to writing generic code _within_ a single MCU in order to share code between devices and board revisions with different layouts, and accounting for the cases where the manufacturer thought it would be fun to define `UART1_TXEN` as 0x01 and `UART2_TXEN` as 0x02 or the like within their mostly-but-not-quite compatible registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write macros such that the preprocessor will expand

```
BIT_SET(DDR(LED), 1);
```

to

```
BIT_SET(DDRB, 5, 1)
```

as described, but that's not really what you want.  `BIT_SET()` is itself a macro, and you want ultimately to get the result of expanding that macro based on the arguments obtained by the other expansion.  *That* you cannot have.  The preprocessor assigns macro arguments to macro parameters before performing any expansions, and with the definition you gave for macro `BIT_SET()`, the preprocessor should always reject your proposed invocation for having the wrong number of arguments.

**Updated to Add**:

On the other hand, the usual trick for indirect token pasting is to wrap it in a double layer of macros.  For instance, the preprocessor expands this stack of macros ...

```
#define CONCAT2(x, y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x, y) CONCAT2(x, y)

#define BIT_MASK(b)  (0x01 << (b))
#define BIT_ON(p,b)  ((p) |= BIT_MASK(b))
#define BIT_OFF(p,b) ((p) &= ~BIT_MASK(b))
#define BIT_SET(p,b,v) (v ? BIT_ON(p,b) : BIT_OFF(p,b))

#define DDRB somevar

#define LED_CODE B
#define LED_BIT  5

#define X_BIT_SET(x, y, v) BIT_SET(CONCAT(x, y ## _CODE), y ## _BIT, v)

X_BIT_SET(DDR, LED, 0)
```

... to

```
(0 ? ((somevar) |= (0x01 << (5))) : ((somevar) &= ~(0x01 << (5))))
```

Note that macro `DDRB` obtained by concatenating `LED` with `_CODE` and expanding the result is itself expanded.  This approach does leave you defining two separate macros for each pin (in this case `LED_CODE` and `LED_BIT`), with names that must adhere to a fixed pattern, but affords a form (e.g. `X_BIT_SET(DDR, LED, 0)`) that is pretty easy to read where it appears in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should do the trick:

Disclaimer: untested and probably buggy, but you get the idea...

```
// Use of PINB, PINC, ... macros and PINB0, PINB1, ... macro from avr/io.h
#define LED   PORT_PIN(PINB, PINB0)

#define PORT_PIN(port, pin) (((unsigned int) (&(port) - &PINB) / (unsigned int) &PINB) \
                             << 4 + (pin))
#define DDR(port_pin)  *(((port_pin) >> 4) & 0xf) \
                         * (unsigned int) (&PINC - &PINB) + &PINB))
#define PORT(port_pin) *(((port_pin) >> 4) & 0xf) \
                         * (unsigned int) (&DDRC - &DDRB) + &DDRB)) 
#define PIN(port_pin)   ((port_pin) & 0xf)

STATIC_ASSERT(&DDRC - &DDRB == &PINC - &PINB);
STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof PINB == 1 && sizeof DDRB == 1);
```

then you can access your macros as:

```
BIT_SET(DDR(LED), PIN(LED), 1);
BIT_SET(PORT(LED), PIN(LED), 0);
```

As a sidenote, in the same vein and depending on your compiler you could also do something like this:

```
typedef struct 
{    
    uint8_t PIN_0: 1;
    uint8_t PIN_1: 1;
    uint8_t PIN_2: 1;
    uint8_t PIN_3: 1;
    uint8_t PIN_4: 1;
    uint8_t PIN_5: 1;
    uint8_t PIN_5: 1;
    uint8_t PIN_6: 1;
    uint8_t PIN_6: 1;
} REG_t;

#define MY_PINB   (*(volatile REG_t *) &PINB)
#define MY_DDRB   (*(volatile REG_t *) &DDRB)
```

and then you could access your pins like this:

```
#define LED  (MY_PINB.PIN0)

LED = 0;
```

Comment: in general, this is the way that TI defines its' bits within a register and by grouping such definitions together defining the register set for a peripheral.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, I decided to use inline functions instead of macros, as suggested by some comments.
This is my result:

```c
// enumeration for I/O ports
typedef enum 
{
    IO_B,
    IO_C,
    IO_D
} ioPort;

// structure representing one I/O pin
typedef struct
{
    ioPort port;
    uint8_t bitIx;
} ioPin;

// converts ioPort to corresponding PORTx pointer
inline volatile uint8_t* port(ioPort iop)
{
    switch(iop)
    {
    case IO_B: return &PORTB;
    case IO_C: return &PORTC;
    case IO_D: return &PORTD;    
    default:   return NULL;
    }
}

// converts ioPort to corresponding DDRx pointer
inline volatile uint8_t* ddr(ioPort iop)
{
    switch(iop)
    {
    case IO_B: return &DDRB;
    case IO_C: return &DDRC;
    case IO_D: return &DDRD;
    default:   return NULL;
    }
}

// sets one bit of a port to given value
static inline void bitSet(volatile uint8_t* port, const uint8_t bitIx, const uint8_t value)
{
    if(port)
    {
        if(value)
            *port |= (1L << bitIx);
        else
            *port &= ~(1L << bitIx);
    }        
}

// configuring where peripheral devices are connected
const ioPin led = {IO_C, 5};
const ioPin button = {IO_C, 6};

// (later in a code)
// setting direction of the pin with an led connected
bitSet(ddr(led.port), led.bitIx, 1);
```

I must admit that, strictly speaking, this is not an answer to my original question, because I asked for a solution with macros. But I hope this could be still useful for someone.